# How to get notification when android mobile user install my application?

Tags: java, android, notifications

I am an android developer. any body give me answer for my question. suppose i developed one application and that application install in android device so, can i get information about that android device.

Comment: you can send user unique id's like IMEI, Android ID or device ID to your webserver and store in databse and check it online.

Comment: ok i will try and it is possible to user install application first time then again uninstall and install same device does not again send that information.

Comment: Yes you can create a flag variable and check before sending email.

Comment: but is it possible without open pop menu like sharing window?

Comment: yes you can send email from code

Comment: Himanshu Agarwal thanks for giving my question response.why down my reputation i don't know. thank you very much. i will try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can send emails from that phone when user runs it

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("message/rfc822");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"recipient@example.com"});
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject of email");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "body of email");
try {
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: This requires the user to actively send an email, if I ever download an app that requires me to send an email to the developer with my device info inside, I'd probably just press back, and the developer will never receive the email. This is a bad solution.

Comment: and is it possible to without open sharing item menu and send mail  ?

Comment: A simple HTTP call should be enough

Answer (score 0):

collect the data when user runs app for first time and send it to a webserver..

Comment: have u any example of that.